# Implicit declaration of function ‘wait’

Tags: c, wait, pid

I am getting a warning > Implicit declaration of function ‘wait’ < and when I run the program it works correctly, I would like to understand why I am getting this warning?

Thanks in advance

**Edit: I forgot to add the library included**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void create (char* program, char** arg_list)
{
  /* put your code here */
  pid_t childPid;
  int status;

  if((childPid = fork()) < 0){
    printf("Failed to fork() --- exiting...\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  else if (childPid == 0){ // --- inside the child process
    if(execvp(program, arg_list) < 0){ // Failed to run the command
      printf("*** Failed to exec %s\n", program);
      exit(1);
    }
  }
  else{ // --- parent process
    while(wait(&status) != childPid)
      printf("...\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: You're missing the `#include` line for the function.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You are probably missing the headers for `wait(2)`:

```
  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <sys/wait.h>
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot the wait library

Comment: Is `sys/types.h` necessary if you aren't utilizing any of the types returned from a `wait` function call?

Comment: @MichaelM I answered based on what the Linux man page had [*at that time*](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) .But it was removed since in this [commit](https://github.com/mkerrisk/man-pages/commit/be26e6997a86654d3af1585ba69486e8af8491bc). The reason it was included earlier was due to types used by `wait` (such as `pid_t`). [continued]

Comment: @MichaelM But including necessary types should be handled by `sys/wait.h` itself rather than requiring users to include them. [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) doesn't require `sys/types.h` either. In summary, `sys/types.h` isn't required for using `wait`!

Comment: @P.P thanks for the clarification! I just wanted to make sure I was understanding correctly. I was able to compile without `sys/types.h` and didn't run into any complications, but I wanted to ensure there were no "hidden" issues I wasn't aware of.

Answer (score 11):

You need to put:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
```

at the top of the program to get the declaration of the function.

This is shown in the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait)